# Python: script sobre una funcion

Tags: python, script

me encuentro con el problema con listar archivos de diferentes nombres, dentro de la variable TARGET. Si tiene un solo contenido lo encuentra para luego copiarlo, pero al agregarle un array para que busque mas nombres sobre la misma funcion no trae los resultados. Se trata de un Script en este lenguaje, para buscar archivos de audios dentro de una carpeta y luego moverlo.

Sepan disculpar pero soy novato con PYTHON.

```
import os
import fnmatch 
import shutil
from ast import walk

target = ('*1514*')  # target = ['*1514*', '*1629*'] ("no funciona!")
initial_dir = '/home/admin/Escritorio/WAV/'
fin = '/home/admin/Escritorio/Audios/'

path_list = [os.path.join(root, file) for root, _, files in os.walk(initial_dir)
                                          for file in fnmatch.filter(files, str(target))]


print(path_list)

audio = walk(path_list)
for audio in path_list:    
    shutil.copy(audio, fin)
```

Desde ya muchas gracias.-

Comment: No entendi el problema.

Comment: al querer listar archivos de la variable "Target", solo me deja si hay un solo parámetro, no así con una lista.

Answer (score 0):

No funciona porque al aplicar `str(target)` a una lista, devuelve una cadena en forma de lista `"['*1514*', '*1629*']"`, lo cual no es útil para [fnmatch.filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html#fnmatch.filter).

Propongo reescribir ese código a algo más simple y entendible. Para saber si una cadena hace match con un elemento de una lista de subcadenas, una opción rápida sería por cada elemento preguntar si ese elemento está `in` en la cadena (o sea en el nombre del archivo):

```
[patron_de_busqueda in nombre_archivo for patron_de_busqueda in target]
```

Produce una lista de coincidencias, con tal que haya una, el archivo calificará para ser copiado (o movido).
No será lo más eficiente del mundo, pero es sencillo y facilita escribir un código más entendible:

```
import os
import shutil

dir_src = '/home/admin/Escritorio/WAV/'
dir_dst = '/home/admin/Escritorio/Audios/'
target = ['1514', '1629']

all_files = os.listdir(dir_src) # Aqui se listan los archivos

for cur_file in all_files:
    src = os.path.join(dir_src, cur_file)
    if os.path.isfile(src) and any([x in cur_file for x in target]):
        # Si la ruta src es un archivo (no directorio, symlink, etc) 
        # y si alguna de las subcadenas de target están dentro del nombre
        dst = os.path.join(dir_dst, cur_file)
        try:
            shutil.move(src, dst) # O copiar con shutil.copy2(src, dst)
        except:
            print("No se pudo copiar/mover el archivo") 
            # Por permisos, no existe la ruta, etc
```

Recordar además la sensibilidad a mayúsculas, si la búsqueda por patrones tiene letras, puedes hacer `x in cur_file.lower()` para que sea insensible. Si las búsquedas son más complejas puedes usar [regex](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+regex), o el módulo [fnmatch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html).